# NODEJS - AXIOS : Error : The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type object at Url.parse

Tags: node.js, axios, cloudant

I am trying to fetch data from a rest API using AXIOS as below:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const axios = require('axios');

var url = 'https://931eb067-05c0-492a-8129-48ebfc27d426-bluemix.cloudant.com/dummy/_design/NEW_VIEW_DESIGN/_view/new-view?include_docs=true';
axios.get({url,auth: {
    username: process.env.account,
    password: process.env.password 
}}).then((res)=>{console.log(res.data);})
.catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
```

I am able to access the metioned URL seperately by providing the credentials but I am getting the below error while using AXIOS

> The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type object at Url.parse

What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
axios.get({url,auth: {
    username: process.env.account,
    password: process.env.password
}}).then((res)=>{console.log(res.data);})
```

Should be

```
axios.get(url, { auth: {
    username: process.env.account,
    password: process.env.password
}}).then((res)=>{console.log(res.data);})
```

Comment: The bracket must be before the name `auth` but you have it after it.

Comment: as pointed out by Amr Saber,  this answer contains invalid javascript, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017967/3303776) answer is the correct one

Answer (score 9):

You have put `url` inside the config confie parameter but it must be before the config.

```
axios.get(url, {auth: {
    username: process.env.account,
    password: process.env.password
}}).then((res)=>{console.log(res.data);})
.catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
```

Comment: Since almost all sites use `https` whether you need to authenticate or not, why would the following code fail with the same error as the author,


`const url = "https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/countries/";`

`const response = await axios.get(url);`

`const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);`

The site does not require a login and I'm using `async/await`.

Comment: @MikeS. if you want seriously help, you need to address a new issue/question with full example and definitions. Using your code I get `ReferenceError: cheerio is not defined`.

Comment: This issue is long past dead and buried. It’s not relevant anymore.